# Create Aurora read replica option is missing from RDS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have PostgreSQL DB running on Version 10.15 for which I like to created an `Aurora Read Replica` as mentioned in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html#Creating%20an%20Aurora%20read%20replica) official document, however in the AWS console I only have the option of `Create Read Replica` only and not `Create Aurora Read Replica`. The option is completely missing.

If I choose to Create Read Replica, it then just create another PostgreSQL instance instead of Aurora PostGres, and that's is not what I want.

P.s: I have auto back-up enabled for that instance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be running **RDS PostegreSQL**, as there is [no Aurora PostegreSQL 10.15](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html).

For the RDS, you **only create read replicas** as indicated in the AWS Console. Aurora replicas are only for Aurora PostgreSQL (not RDS PostgreSQL).

Comment: It seems like it used to be possible in the past, but not any longer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correct, you have an RDS PostgreSQL instance (not Aurora) and want to create an Aurora PostgreSQL Read Replica from it. With steps mention on documentation link you shared.

This is possible and I could reproduce it, but not for all version.

I tested with MySQL, not with PostgreSQL, but the mechanism is the same.

I created one RDS MySQL (not Aurora) version `5.7.33` and from this one I can create Aurora Read Replica, as you can see from picture below.

[image: RDS - Create Aurora Read Replica]

The other one I created RDS MySQL (not Aurora) version `8.0.23`, this one doesn't show me the option to create Aurora Read Replica.

[image: RDS - Without Create Aurora Read Replica]

---

**Update**

The rules to have this option enable is:

1. The same major version between RDS and Aurora
2. Minor version equal or higher on Aurora.

With versions we have today on RDS PostgreSQL and Aurora PostgreSQL, none match the rules above.
But we have a match for MySQL, as I showed.

If you want to migrate from RDS to Aurora, even though this options is not available you have other options, like snapshot and DMS.

Comment: cool, why didn't you try doing with with Postgres if you know mechanism are the same?

Comment: See my update with rules to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Aurora MySQL,
Aurora MySQL 2. x versions are compatible with MySQL 5.7 and
Aurora MySQL 1. x versions are compatible with MySQL 5.6.

When creating a new Aurora MySQL DB cluster (including restoring a snapshot), you have the option of choosing compatibility with either MySQL 5.7 or MySQL 5.6.

This implies that When creating the RDS for MySQL instance, you are limited to versions of MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 (if you intend to create Aurora MySQL read replicas)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.2044.html